# ArcMap crashes after using "geocode addresses" tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geocoding, arctoolbox

I'm working with ArcGIS 10.2 in a project where I need to publish my own geoprocessing service in order to Geocode a table of addresses. I tried creating models in model builder then publishing them and everything was working fine. But after trying to publish a model wher the input is an Excel file that I convert to a tableau and then geocode it, ArcMap crashed and since then everytime I try to run a model containing "Geocode addresses tool" ArcMap crashes. I tried to run a simple "Geocode addresses" from the toolbox and the toolbox crashes.

I tried deleting temp files and changing the "normal.mxt" and rebooting and the problem persists. I find this behavior strange since the same models were working before even in ArcGIS Server and now everytime a model is using "Geocode addresses" ArcMap crashes in the "geocoding addresses" step.

Comment: I'm not positive about 10.2  but earlier versions had a limit of records one could geocode depending on your license.

Comment: Actually i'm using a table of 4 records i dont think the limit is the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that a [patch](http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/view/productid/160/metaid/1993) by ESRI is available for this case scenario:

> Esri® announces the ArcGIS 10.2 (Desktop, Engine) Geocoding with Composite Locator Service Patch. This patch addresses an issue in which ArcGIS Desktop and Engine applications may crash when batch geocoding against a composite locator that is published to ArcGIS Server